# How can i add the following kind of animation for my Imageview

Tags: android, imageview, horizontal-scrolling, background-foreground

please find attached my video, which shows the animation/design for my Imageview.
How can i add something like this?[first you see the normal imageview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksGBz.png)

[after scrolling, the text goes into the foreground and the Image into the Background. How is this possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13NBU.png)

Comment: Try Co-ordinator Layout with Collapsing toolbar check this...http://www.androidauthority.com/using-coordinatorlayout-android-apps-703720/

Comment: Guess you're looking for CollapsingToolbarLayout. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to achieve this simply you can do it like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />


        <!--your layout -->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```